# how to reset password for user in asp.net membershipprovider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

how can I reset a userspassword after he reached the maxInvalidPasswordAttempts using aspnet membership provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is in the context of an admin user overwriting an existing user password (or a forgot my password reset type function) with a new known password. There is a *trick* involved since you need to first reset the password 'randomly' to get a known password to pass to `ResetPassword`:

```
    public bool ResetUserPassword(Guid userId, string newPassword)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(userId, false);
        // Unlock the user account if necessary
        user.UnlockUser();
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
        // Trick here is that have to reset it randomly first to be able to provide a new known password
        string tmpPassword = user.ResetPassword();
        return user.ChangePassword(tmpPassword, newPassword);
     }
```

There is also another way, which is to copy the `Password` (hash), `PasswordFormat` and `PasswordSalt` fields in the `aspnet_Membership` table directly from another known user to the 'lost' one, but that is a horrible hack.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here... [MembershipProvider.ResetPassword()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

or [MembershipProvider.UnlockUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.unlockuser) to unlock them